# Return Expired Records Every Five Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I'm working on a query that will return records that are soon to expire in 30, 15, 10, 5, 0 days. Additionally, I want to return expired certs every five days after expiration.

It seems like the results are correct and are returned in less than a second, but is there a more elegant way of setting this up? More specifically, the last line where I'm trying to return expired records every five days?

```
declare @DateVar datetime
set @DateVar = Convert(date, GetDate())

; with Exp as
(
    select a.UID, a.UName, a.Expiration_Date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), Expiration_Date) as 'NumberOfDays'
    from Table1 a
    inner join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
    inner join Table3 c on a.UID = c.UID 
)
, DateToSendCalc as
(
select *, DATEADD(DAY, -NumberOfDays, Expiration_Date) as DateToSendNotification 
from Exp
)
Select distinct a.UID, a.UName, a.Expiration_Date, DateToSendNotification,
NumberOfDays
from DateToSendCalc a 
where NumberOfDays in (30, 15, 10, 5, 0)
or NumberOfDays like '-%5'
```

An example of what the returned data should look like:

If the query was executed today (Jan 15, 2024):

| ID | Expires | Days Expired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-22 00:00:00.000 | 7 |
| 12 | 2024-01-10 10:00:00.000 | -5 |
| 16 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00.000 | -15 |

If the query was executed today (Jan 20, 2024):

| ID | Expires | Days Expired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-22 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 12 | 2024-01-10 10:00:00.000 | -10 |
| 16 | 2023-12-31 00:00:00.000 | -20 |

Comment: without the original tables and the data that produce your result, it is iimpossibke to help see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How do you define *more elegant*? What are your expectations? Are you looking to improve performance?

Comment: Have you considered using the 'remainder'/'modulus' operator: `or NumberOfDays % 5 = 0`

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Prefilter you data with something like `Expiration_Date <= DATEADD(day 30, @DateVar)`. If `Expiration_Date ` is indexed, this will reduce the amount of data initially retrieved by the first CTE.  (2) Once you have limited the data with #1, you can simplify the final condition to `where NumberOfDays % 5 = 0`. The `%` is the modulus (division remainder) operator.

Comment: WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), Expiration_Date)) % 5 = 0

Comment: Comparing a number to a string is clearly wrong...